# rake db:migrate issue on heroku

Tags: ruby, macos, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following [Ruby on Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial)
 and once I have pushed all my code to Github, I tried to deploy on Heroku using following commands -

```
$ heroku create
$ git push heroku master
$ heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I am getting following error

```
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... failed
 !    App not found
```

If I try to access my app I get Page does not exist. Following is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

I've tried some of the other solutions for the similar questions posted here, but none of them resolved my issue.

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --app <app-name>
heroku pg:reset DATABASE
heroku run:detached rake db:migrate
```

Ruby - 2.0.0
Rails - 4.0.4
OS - Mac OSX Maverick

Comment: what does the command `heroku apps` give?

Comment: It gives name of all my apps and it contains `sample-static`, the one I renamed